# Facebook share button not working on mobile site

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-sharer

I have implemented Facebook share button in to the mobile site to share an image with image name and url on Facebook. The button works well on desktop site - it posts the image, image name and url. The button works on iPad as well, but doesn't work on mobile platform it's seems as a conflict between m.facebook and m.oursitename because when i click on share facebook button i takes on facebook page but facebook ask me an url that i would like to share but i already implemneted the url in the code.

May you help me please?

Comment: Got the same problem here. My target crowd is not using desktop... so i reach... nobody...

Comment: Same problem here. Haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Did Facebook jdk loaded succeed?

I'm using bellow code, works well for me

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/zh_TW/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8"></script>
```

using above code instead of Facebook share-button step 2:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/zh_TW/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the FB developer site, you have to uncheck the mobile Iframe option. When I did this, I was able to generate buttons that work for Mobile and desktop.